# VBA acting up, methods failed, sheets disapear

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a code that extracts certain data from website, adds it to the sheet, then checks what day it is and modifies progress bar (only columns in sheet). Then the code saves the current result on sheet as image and finally sets it as wallpaper. At first I had to deal with "unknown" problems. I ran the code ańd it failed. But when I debugged it step by step it ran perfectly. I figured out that my Workbook had to be corrupted. So I copied the VBA to a new workbook and finally the code ran OK. After few days I started to get errors like cells object global failed etc. I read that it happens when certain objects are not sufficiently defined so I added `thisworkbook.sheets(1).cells` to every cells object that error appeared at. This didn't help since the errors started popping even in the most fundamental basic stuff. So I shift started the workbook at revealed the problem. Or I THINK.. The macro removes current sheet every time I run it. Few days back it did't. Simply nothing has changed.. I will paste the code below. Is the workbook corrupted again and how does one prevent it?

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias "SystemParametersInfoA" _
                        (ByVal uAction As Long, ByVal uParam As Long, _
                         ByVal lpvParam As Any, ByVal fuWinIni As Long) As Long

Public Const SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
Public Const SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = &H2
Public Const SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = &H1
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub Auto_Open()
    Call getDataFromWebsite
    Call weekProgress
    Call saveSheet
    Call changeWallpaper
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.Quit
End Sub

Sub getDataFromWebsite()
Dim x As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim HtmlCon As HTMLDocument
Dim element As Object
Dim ArrivalTime

    On Error GoTo Handler
    x = "someWebsite"
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Navigate (x)
    IE.Visible = False
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set HtmlCon = IE.document
    Set element = HtmlCon.getElementsByClassName("someclassname")
    ArrivalTime = element(0).innerText
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 15).Value = ArrivalTime
Handler:
    IE.Quit
End Sub


Sub weekProgress()
Dim caseResult As String
Dim offsetDayIndex As Integer
Const dayBarLenght = 2

    Select Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Date, 2)
        Case 1
            caseResult = "Monday"
            offsetDayIndex = 0
        Case 2
            caseResult = "Tuesday"
            offsetDayIndex = 1
        Case 3
            caseResult = "Wednesday"
            offsetDayIndex = 2
        Case 4
            caseResult = "Thursday"
            offsetDayIndex = 3
        Case 5
            caseResult = "Friday"
            offsetDayIndex = 4
        Case Else
            caseResult = "Monday"
    End Select
DoEvents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(24, 11).Value = caseResult
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(31, 5), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(31, 12)).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
If Not caseResult = "Monday" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(31, 5), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(31, 4 + (dayBarLenght * offsetDayIndex))).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End If

End Sub



Sub saveSheet()
Dim oCht As Object
Dim zoom_coef
Dim area

zoom_coef = 100 / ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Parent.Windows(1).Zoom
Set area = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).PageSetup.PrintArea)
DoEvents
area.CopyPicture xlPrinter

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    DoEvents
    Set oCht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    oCht.Chart.Paste
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    oCht.Chart.Export Filename:="somepath\savedImage.bmp", Filtername:="bmp"
    DoEvents
    oCht.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub changeWallpaper()
Dim strImagePath As String

    strImagePath = "somepath\savedImage.bmp"
    Call SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0&, strImagePath, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)

End Sub






Sub saveSheetBackup()
Dim oCht
Worksheets("List1").Range("B2:Q37").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set oCht = Charts.Add
    DoEvents
    oCht.Paste
    DoEvents
    oCht.Export Filename:="somepath\savedImage.bmp", Filtername:="bmp"
    DoEvents
    oCht.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had an epiphany. I have substituted the `Thisworkbook.Close` with simple `Application.Quit` with alerts disabled and this did the trick. I still don't quite understand why shutting down workbook without saving would delete the sheet altogether. Someone can enlighten me?